# How to assert execution of a function / How to assert memory does get uninitialised?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, initialization, static-assert

As we all know, it is good practice to assume the dumbest possible user.
I am writing a library that does allocate memory in its use. I would like to make it impossible that this memory gets leaked, I already have a function that does this cleanup, all I need is to force the user to call this function. (The user would be a developer using this library)

My first thought was to give the user a token for initialization that handles the cleanup in its destructor, that is required for anything in my library. This seems like it is harder for the user as they will have to keep this token and this token always has to exist, an initialization function returning this token could have its return value be ignored and immediately deleted, invalidating the token.

I would prefer a way that allows initialization without returning any value to the user and without the user having to care about keeping this token. Forcing the user to initialize can be done relatively simple by using an initialized flag set to `false` until set to `true` by the initialization function and requiring its value to be `true` everywhere.

My second thought was, to use `static_assert()`, but I could not find a good condition that would only be fulfilled if the function would be called / executed. Unlike for types, there is no `std::gets_called()`, `std::will_be_executed()`, `std::is_happening()` for functions comparable to `std::is_arithmetic()`, `std::is_class()`, `std::is_same()` from [<type_trais>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits).

The most simple solution would of course be to claim that the user is not using the library correctly, but I would like to forbid the user to not use the library correctly. Are there any good practices or common approaches I could not find? Are there ways to implement the token system without any workload on the user? Are there any conditions for `static_assert()` that would force execution of this function, somewhere in the future / at the end? Are there any other ways which ensure that the memory cleanup is performed?

Additional note on unused return values:
The destructor is called immediately after the value is returned, the value / object does not further as an anonymous / inaccessible variable until leaving the current execution scope, if this would not be the case the token solution would be perfectly acceptable for me.

Comment: _"I would like to make it impossible that this memory gets leaked, I already have a function that does this cleanup"_ - Why? Use `std::vector<resource>` and you don't need any cleanup functions.

Comment: It seems that you are using global state in your library. You could avoid the whole issue by simply putting all state in a class object which is constructed by the user for initialization (or returned by an initializing function) and have it include the whole interface that the user would use. The user is forced to take care of the object as long as they want to use your library and once they let it die, its destructor will perform clean-up.

Comment: @user17732522 I believe what you are suggesting is similar to my token solution, where this token would be an object of type `class token`, refer to the question for my thoughts about that solution. If your idea is different from my approach, please explain further. Also, this would wrap my library into a class, this would create many nested subclasses and obfuscate the interface, I am not sure if I would want that.

Comment: @ZwergofPhoenix You sound like you are thinking in C idioms.  I would try to change that.

Comment: @ZwergofPhoenix If the user is only able to access functionality of the library through this "token", then they automatically have to keep that object alive. Basically it is RAII: The user does an open/init call to the library which should return the object representing the library resource. As long as the user keeps using the library through the object the resource is alive. Once they let the object go out-of-scope the destructor automatically performs cleanup. They can't use the library without the object managing the resource. Exactly the same way that e.g. `std::ifstream` works for files.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I was trying to use `std::vector<>` but I need to handle references as well, and I can`t have a private constructor or move an object into this vector inside its public constructor. Also, I think there might be some problems with static members and having some internal local variables that may not be destroyed until cleanup.

Comment: @user17732522, thanks for clarifying. That seems like it is a possibility, even though I believe `std::ifstream` does not provide too much functionality to obfuscate its functionality. If I however think of having to use functionalities like opencv through an object that encapsulates its functionality, I don't feel great about that. I might have to think about that again to decide if it's worth trying.

Comment: This discussion is taking place in a vacuum.  Tell us more about your library (add it to your question).

Comment: "_but I need to handle references as well"_ - You can't have arrays of references however you do it. You can use `std::reference_wrapper`s though.